# PHP select form a mysql table and order by another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my MySQL Database:

- customer
- customer_billing

*customer* table has the columns columns

- sequence
- company

the *customer_billing* table has the columns

- sequence
- customer_seq

i am running a select query on the *customer_billing* table and then within a while loop a select query in the *customer* table like this:

```
$sql="SELECT *, SUM(quantity*unitprice) as customertotal from customer_billing where resellerid = '' and salesmanid = '' and producttype = '".$_GET["producttype"]."' group by customer_seq ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $sql2="SELECT * from customer where sequence = '".$result["customer_seq"]."' and company_status = '' ";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
}
```

i want to be able to order the results displayed by `company ASC` from the *customer* table

i have tried order_by customer_seq by obviously this only orders the sequence numbers

i have also tried doing order by `company ASC` on the *customer* table query but this didnt work either

how can i get round this?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output example (best way to do this is to provide [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) )

Comment: It's `order by` not `order_by`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a join between customer and customer_billing on customer_seq and add company to the group by clause.

This way you should be able to order it by company.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Joins` and no need to use a `second query` try this,

```
$sql="SELECT c.*,ct.*, SUM(ct.quantity*ct.unitprice) as customertotal FROM
    customer_billing ct , custom c WHERE ct.resellerid = '' AND ct.salesmanid = '' 
    AND c.company_status = '' AND c.sequence=ct.customer_seq AND 
    ct.producttype = '".$_GET["producttype"]."'
    GROUP BY ct.customer_seq ORDER BY c.company ASC ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in a single query using [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). Should be smth like this:

```sql
SELECT cb.customer_seq, c.sequence, c.company, SUM(quantity*unitprice) as customertotal
FROM customer_billing AS cb JOIN customer AS c
     ON cb.sequence = c.sequence
WHERE cb.resellerid = ''
  AND cb.salesmanid = ''
  AND cb.producttype = '$_GET["producttype"]'
  AND c.company_status = ''
GROUP BY cb.customer_seq, c.company
ORDER BY c.company
```

Comment: this is just displaying one customer record